# Are WCF + Callbacks suitable for sending commands to the client?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to create a WCF service for our existing product.
The service should provide normal "webservice" features (one-way), but also act independently.

Sample scenario:

1. The client connects to the server
2. The server saves the client in a collection
3. Now I use an admin client / database entry to tell the client to do sth. (For example change config for log4net/NHibernate)

I've read some things about callbacks (mostly a chat system), but I'm still not sure if this will work.

Now my question is, will WCF be suitable for such a scenario or should I use TCPClient/TCPListener?

Comment: I'm always skeptical of callbacks because where will you store them? You must store them in an in-memory collection. That does not work well with clustering (required for HA) and also IIS worker processes can die at any time, closing the callback channel.

Comment: short answer, yes, provided your clients can open tcp connections to your server so a duplex channel can be set up.

Comment: This service should run as a standalone service / Windows Service and clustering is not planned, because our customers use max ~100 clients simultaneously

Comment: What do you do if the server physically breaks? Or the server must be rebooted for patching. You probably need an HA strategy, which usually is two servers behind a load balancer. I'm bringing this up because in my mind this influences whether callbacks are a good idea.